# How to merge text string based on value of another column in VBA?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and MS Excel in general so pardon my ignorance. 
I am trying to make a macro that detects each unique Name in column A and merge all the Comments associated with the Name, in column B and having it delimited on a new line.

The number of names and comments will vary which is why I was looking at a macro in VBA. Do I need to include SQL too to make it work?

What I have:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RYgq.png]

What I want:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EmOh.png]

Comment: I'm honestly not sure why you'd want this.  Excel works best with your current setup (the screenshot of "What I have").  You could just filter for John Smith for example and see all of his comments.  Various other excel formulas and functions will expect a setup like you currently have as well in order to calculate properly.  Is there a specific reason you need to transform the data?

Comment: The initial project was to was map each cell value onto a fill-able PDF form. This part has since been completed as it only contained integers but the requirements have since changed to also include strings of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range, cll As Range
    Dim str As String

    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With

    lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range("A2:A" & lngLastRow)

    lngCount = 2
    str = str & Range("B2").Value & vbNewLine

    For Each cll In rng
        If cll.Value = cll.Offset(1, 0).Value Then
            str = str & cll.Offset(1, 1).Value & vbNewLine
        Else
            Range("C" & lngCount & ":C" & cll.Row).MergeCells = True
            Range("C" & lngCount) = Left(str, Len(str) - 1)
            str = cll.Offset(1, 1).Value & vbNewLine
            lngCount = cll.Row + 1
        End If
    Next


End Sub
```